# laravel stored procedure error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am encountering the error below when trying to use a stored procedure to register an user.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1318 Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE tls_db.insert_customer; expected 7, got 0 (SQL: call insert_customer)

```
controller
    $user   = array(
                'email' => Input::get('email'),
                'password' => Input::get('password'),
                'username' => Input::get('username'),
                'PhoneNumber' => Input::get('PhoneNumber'),
                'CustomerName' => Input::get('CustomerName'),
                'CustomerSurname' => Input::get('CustomerSurname'),
                'CustomerAddress' => Input::get('CustomerAddress'));
                $data = new user($user);
                $data->save();
                user::storedProcedureInsert_customer();
                return Redirect::to('/');
model
    public static function storedProcedureInsert_customer() {
         return DB::statement('call insert_customer');
    }
```

Comment: Fixed some minor grammar and formatting

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert_customer` procedure expects seven arguments, but you haven't provided any.

You're best off calling it with a parameterized statement, like so:

`DB::statement('call insert_customer(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [Input::get('email'), Input::get('password'), Input::get('PhoneNumber'), Input::get('CustomerName'), Input::get('CustomerSurname'), Input::get('CustomerAddress')]);`

Comment: so are you saying its ment to be like this  DB::statement('call insert_customer(email, password, PhoneNumber, CustomerName, CustomerSurname, CustomerAddress, username)',
     [
     Input::get('Email'), 
     Input::get('Password'), 
     Input::get('PhoneNumber'), 
     Input::get('CustomerName'),
     Input::get('CustomerSurname'),
     Input::get('Username'),
     Input::get('CustomerAddress')]);       cause i am getting this error now

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'field list' (SQL: call insert_customer(email, password, PhoneNumber, CustomerName, CustomerSurname, CustomerAddress, username))